# Node mssql module error on AWS Lambda

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am facing an issue with the `mssql` node module, it is working very well in the local environment but when I deployed the code base into AWS lambda and from there if I execute the function it is failing for some reason below is the error.

> START RequestId: 5ea5fc6b-9d45-11e7-9dca-ffdf71e8f823
>   Version: $LATEST2017-09-19T14:18:28.733Z  5ea5fc6b-9d45-11e7-9dca-ffdf71e8f823
>   SQL connection error { ConnectionError: Failed to connect to 10.71.12.16:49001 in 15000ms
>   at Connection.tedious.once.err

Note: even in local it should be in the allocated network to get the response.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a networking issue. Is 10.71.12.16:49001 accessible from the outside world?

Comment: No, it is not accessible

Comment: Is that inside a VPC in AWS? If that's the case, you need to configure your Lambda to run inside the same VPC.

Comment: I have selected no VPC

Comment: So that may be it. Your database is _inside_ a VPC so you have to configure your Lambda accordingly.

Comment: Have you fixed it?

Comment: Not yet will update you once it is fixed

Comment: Hi shaik, have you fixed it ? now I also encountered the same access issue!